# Exporting Security Group Memberships in Batch

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, batch

I have the following command but it doesn't work when put into a batch file:

```
dsquery group DC=domain,DC=com -name "Group Name" | dsget group -members | dsget user -display >> "Group Name.txt"
```

If I execute through cmd line it works fine but not when executed from within a batch, what am I missing?

(Note: Powershell isn't an option otherwise I would use that believe me !)

Comment: What do you get? Nothing? Also, I would wrap my OU of the group in " " too.

Comment: It just writes the command to the text file!

Comment: If you remove the >> "Textfile.txt" does it write the info to the console?

Comment: Just loops the command and outputs nothing

Comment: I can't repro any problem on my lab domain. Your command line works (obviously w/ the path to my rootDSE substituted in it) just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it without the OU / Path to the object. I know it is often encourage to use it, but it seems to cause me trouble more often than not with DSTools.

```
dsquery group -name "The Group in Question" | dsget group -members | dsget user -display >> "Group Name.txt"
```

I just tested this, and it did work for my group from a batch File.